# How to install and configure apictl tool for WSO2 3.1.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

With reference to available document (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-controller/getting-started-with-wso2-api-controller), I did below steps for WSO2 API 3.1.0 CLI tool,

1. Navigate to API Management Tooling Page and download the tool relevant to your platform (Linux).
2. Extract the downloaded archive of the CTL Tool to the desired location (apictl-3.1.1-linux-x64.tar.gz).
3. Navigate to the working directory where the executable CTL Tool resides. Execute the following command to start the CTL Tool.

Now,
When I start executing any command ./atpcli command, I fall with below error,

```
apictl: MainConfig: File Not Found: /home/<current_user>/.wso2apictl/main_config.yaml Reason: open /home/<current_user>/.wso2apictl/main_config.yaml: no such file or directory
```

So, I created .wso2apictl directory and blank main_config.yaml file.
But I got new error,

```
apictl: Error reading /home/amitofile/.wso2apictl/main_config.yaml. Reason: exportDirectory cannot be blank
```

Am I doing anything wrong or documentation is incomplete?

Note:
There is no way given to add environment manually in main_config.yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

We have fixed the issue and released a new version of the APICTL. Kindly use https://github.com/wso2/product-apim-tooling/releases/tag/v3.1.2